# Learning resources on cavity QED

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, education, cavity-qed

Recently, I have been studying lecture notes on Circuit QED by Steve Girvin to learn about superconducting circuits. I am currently in the chapter about cavity QED. The description in the notes are good, but I would like to learn more about them in a rigorous manner. Hence, I am looking for learning resources on the topic.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! For your question, it may be helpful to specify a bit. E.g. what do you mean by "rigorous"? Are you interested in theoretical cavity QED or experimental systems? Is there anything in particular that sparked your interest in these notes?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Wolpertinger. I am specifically interested in the derivation of the Purcell Effect and study of Jaymes Cumming Hamiltonian for different cases, e.g., including damping term for the qubit or cavity. My master's project in experimental NMR quantum computing dealt with preventing qubit dephasing with quantum control, so am interested in this particular topic. I hope to join an experimental QED group for my PhD., so I am unsure if this knowledge will benefit me. I am reading lecture notes by Nathan K Langford and Steven Girvin to learn about superconducting circuits